# why can't "_all" field be enabled in ElasticSearch 6.0?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the index "index" and type "fulltext" created, but when I was trying to enable "_all" field with (as suggested by https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/mapping-all-field.html):

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/index?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "mapping": {
    "fulltext": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": true   
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

The message I got was as follows:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "unknown setting [index.mapping.fulltext._all.enabled] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "unknown setting [index.mapping.fulltext._all.enabled] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

How can I correct it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t change that anymore in 6.0. 
Basically the field does not exist anymore but the feature is still there but implemented differently. So you don’t need to care about it anymore.

That’s what the first lines of documentation you linked to are saying:

> _all may no longer be enabled for indices created in 6.0+, use a custom field and the mapping copy_to parameter

Comment: it says "may"..so you mean _all is totally not supported in 6.0+?

Comment: @dadoonet- You mentioned **feature is still there but implemented differently**. So how I can implement this? Can you give me an example of it. I want to search a string without specifying the field name.

Comment: The default behavior of elasticsearch does that automatically. ie. Search with `GET _search?q=foo` and you'll be searching in "all" fields.